# Using PowerShell, how do I delete a line from a text file by its line number?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, say I want to delete line 5 from a 10 line text file using the line number, how is this done?

Comment: Is there any unique content on line 5 of these files that we can key off of?  Are the number of lines in each file all the same?  Which version of Powershell are you able to use?

Answer (score 6):

Not as clean as I would like but does the trick:

```
$content = Get-Content foo.txt
$content | Foreach {$n=1}{if ($n++ -ne 5) {$_}} > foo.txt
```

If you have [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) installed, you can use the Skip-Object cmdlet to make this a little nicer:

```
$content = Get-Content foo.txt
$content | Skip -Index 4 > foo.txt
```

Note that the -Index parameter is 0 based which is why I used 4 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
(cat SomeFile.txt) -replace (cat SomeFile.txt)[4],"" | sc SomeFile.txt -Force
```

Or in a slightly more readable form:

```
$LineNumber = 5
$Contents = Get-Content Somefile.txt
$Contents -replace $Contents[$LineNumber -1],"" | Set-Content Somefile.txt
```

Although I agree with Keith. Skip-Object can be very useful if you have the PSCX module installed.

Comment: That's not really appropriate as it will replace all occurrences of $Contents[$LineNumber -1] (which might be a word or a sentence) on the entire file.

Comment: Also it leaves a blank line in my experience, I ended up with a text file full of blank lines, I'm currently looking for a solution that is not replacing something with ""